# How to replace part of Connection String?

Tags: c#, string, connection-string

I'm using c# and I need to replace a string with other data.
This is the string, the servername, user1 and 380kj data and length can change.

```
"Data Source=servername;User ID=user1;Password=380kj"
```

I want this result:

```
"Data Source=servername;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX"
```

I have done an IndexOf on User ID and Password but I don't know how to get the exact count to use the remove function so I can then insert the XXXXX into the string.

```
   int index = SaleDatabase.ConnectionString.IndexOf("User ID=");
   int index2 = SaleDatabase.ConnectionString.IndexOf(";Password");
```

What can I do?

thanks...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228599.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx

Comment: What if the password has a semicolon in it, then it will be inside quotes!

Comment: Good chance this could be dealth with using ConnectionStringBuilders http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For *general* strings, use `string.Replace` or `Regex.Replace`. Don't mess around with IndexOf nonsense as it makes code needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `String.Replace` method, but it seems that in your case you are editing a database connection string, in which case you should use the specific ConnectionStringBuilder for that connection string, such as:

```
string connStr = "Data Source=servername;User ID=user1;Password=380kj";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connStr);
sb.UserID = "XXXXX";
sb.Password = "XXXXX";
connStr = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely use the `ConnectionStringBuilder` in this specific case as @M.A. Hamm suggested. But for completeness, you can also do something like this with a simple `Regex.Replace`. Something like:

```
    Regex r = new Regex(@"User ID=[^;]*");
    String newString = r.Replace(s,"User ID=XXXX");
```

Will look for text starting with `User ID=` and capture all characters up to the next `;` (note: if user id contains a `;` this would break - but it probably would have broken anyway and would need to have been escaped). Then we just replace the matched string with our new string.

Doing the same for `Password=` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: If escaped it would have quotes around it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not split the string by using Split Method by character (";"). Result will be array. Then u can fetch value from result array using simple linq or foreach loop

Comment: And reassemble with String.Join.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `string.Format` and generate a new `string`, for sample:

```
public static string GenerateConnectionString(string dataSource, string user, string password)
{
   return string.Format("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2}", dataSource, user, password);
}
```

Some solutions can be very simple. Read more about [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)